# How to get ClickEvent from Button with overlay in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a grid that contains several smaller images that are overlayed by a half-transparent image.
I now want to get the MouseUpEvent from the smaller images below the overlay.
So far, I didn't manage to do so. I didn't find anything on this here.

My .xaml looks like this:

```
<Grid>
  <Image x:Name="Button1" ...  MouseLeftButtonUp="WP7LargeTile_LeftClick"/>
  <Image x:Name="Button2" ...  MouseLeftButtonUp="WP7LargeTile_LeftClick"/>
  <Image x:Name="GradientOverlay" ... />
</Grid>
```

The overlay covers both buttons and that's why I think the event is not raised. But what can I do to get the events from the buttons and have them overlayed at the same time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `IsHitTestVisible` property

```
<Grid>
  <Image x:Name="Button1" ...  MouseLeftButtonUp="WP7LargeTile_LeftClick"/>
  <Image x:Name="Button2" ...  MouseLeftButtonUp="WP7LargeTile_LeftClick"/>
  <Image x:Name="GradientOverlay" IsHitTestVisible="False" ... />
</Grid>
```